# Matching String regular expression in java?

Tags: java, regex

I have below lines of java code.

```
            String string1 = "SAMPLE STRING";
            String string2 = "SAMPLE*";

            string2 = string2.replaceAll("\\*",".*").trim().toUpperCase();

            if(string1.matches(string2)){
                System.out.println("true");
            }else{
                System.out.println("false");
            }
```

Here i dont understand the regex meaning here. what does it mean? Can anyone please help me?

Thanks!

Comment: You can go through the documentation of : - [`Pattern Class`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html)

Answer (score 2):

So your regex here is `"\\*"` which simply means character `*`. The `replaceAll()` here will replace all `*` characters in `string2` with `.*`.

This is a common replace to have people use simplified regexes (like the ones used to match files, e.g. `*.exe`) and convert it to a [PCRE regex](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perl_Compatible_Regular_Expressions), which is the regex used in Java.

Answer (score 0):

Regex "\*" simply means '*', when applied on string2 = SAMPLE* by replaceAll() the string2 became SAMPLE.* and this is again a regex used by Matcher for match().

"SAMPLE.*" simply accepts everything followed by "SAMPLE"

Hence, "SAMPLE STRING" matched "SAMPLE.*".

Similarly, "SAMPLE ", "SAMPLE 123SSS", "SAMPLE" etc. will match.
But, " SAMPLE STRING" doesn't matches pattern "SAMPLE.*"